# Ignored custom messages with annotation-based validation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, validation

Basically, I've created a custom annotation cross-field validation with a validator implementing `ConstraintValidator`.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = SomeValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface SomeAnnotation {
   String message() default "{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}";

   Class<?>[] groups() default {};

   Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator implementation is pretty basic - it checks if some fields are empty (or not) according to a specific, selected entity type. The JSON error message returned by the server contains correct paths to variables with errors, but - unfortunately - it completely ignores the message I pass, replacing it with `CustomAnnotationClass.entityClassInCamelCase.path.to.variable`. I even tried using plain strings (without `{ }`) or default message codes (for example, from `@NotNull`, that works for other fields) with no luck.

This is the code I use to set the message:

```
constraintValidatorContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(getMessage()).addPropertyNode("someField").addPropertyNode("id")
                      .addConstraintViolation();
```

(The only difference between other fields is the number of nodes and the method invocation that returns a string, but since I have no problem with the variable paths and ALL messages are ignored, I think it's irrelevant.)

A (slightly modified) example of returned JSON:

```
{"fieldErrors":[{"path":"someField.id","message":"MyAnnotationClass.someEntity.someField.id"}]}
```

Is this an incorrect way to set the message or am I missing some configurations?

Comment: Try to check BindingResults' error to see which paths are used and specify them

Comment: The thing is - I don't have direct access to it, validation is handled internally through @Valid annotation on entity parameters in controllers' methods. That's one of the reasons why I decided to use custom constraints.

Comment: You can add BindingResults as a parameter in your controller's method and check there.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I'll check it out later.